# Multivariate T distribution?

Tags: joint-distribution, t-distribution

Suppose $(Y_1,Y_2)^T \sim N((0,0)^T,\Sigma)$, where $$
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 
\sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\
\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$ $T_1= \frac{\bar{Y_1}}{S_1/\sqrt{n}}$ and $T_2= \frac{\bar{Y_2}}{S_2/\sqrt{n}}$ are the T test statistics. If $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$ and $S_1=S_2$, then the joint distribution of $T_1, T_2$ is multivariate t distribution with the shape matrix equal to the correlation matrix corresponding to $\Sigma$ and $df=2n-2$. What is the joint distribution of $T_1, T_2$ if $\sigma_1 \ne \sigma_2$ ? Can I estimate it by the multivariate t distribution with shape matrix equal to the correlation matrix corresponding to $\Sigma$ and $df=n-1$ ?

Comment: Have you noticed that the distribution of $(T_1,T_2)$ is unchanged when you replace the $Y_i$ by $Y_i/\sigma_i$?  Thus, without any loss of generality, you may assume (at the outset) that $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=1$ and your question goes away.